# batchDelete in GMail API using Google Apps Scripting

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to get the batchDelete method to work correctly using Google Apps Scripting,  I am able to properly log in using OAuth2 to access my end user account, however when I try to pass in the Ids of the messages that I want to batch delete, I always get a "Backend Error" Code 500.  If I remove the payload from the request, this error goes away and it says that valid Ids need to be specified.  No matter how I try to pass in the payload using URLFetchApp, I get this error.  I am sure I am doing something wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the portion of the code in question.

```
...
var payload2 = 
{
    "ids:" [
         "test",
         "test2"
        ]
}
payload2 = JSON.stringify(payload2);

options = 
   { 
      headers: 
      {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      },
      "ContentType": "application/json",
      "Method": "POST",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "payload": payload2
    };

  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) +"/messages/batchDelete";

results = getResponseFromURL( url, options );

if( results == null || results == "" )
{
    Logger.log("Successfully deleted " + totalMessages + " messages for " + emailAddress );
}
else
{
  Logger.log( "The Results: " + results.toString() )
} 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the above script.  It was the first time that I had used the URLFetchApp API and I was unaware that the contentType and method parameters are case sensitive.  To fix the problem, I just changed the case in the options parameters like this.

```
options = {
....
"contentType": "application/json",
"method": "POST",
...
};
```